# How can I determine username from the Url of a remote repository?

Tags: git, github, git-remote

Before to pull a project from Git repository, I want to check if the git user name is in the URL of remote repository.

Eg: https://usernameAA@remote => if git username == "usernameAA" OK to pull.

I can get the URL with `git ls-remote --get-url` and finding username with `git config user.name`

How can I determine if username from the Url of a remote repository is equal to username to associate commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not extract the username from the url returned by `git ls-remote --get-url`:

```
username=$(git ls-remote --get-url origin | cut -d@ -f1 | cut -d/ -f3| cut -d: -f1)
```

The `last cut -d: -f1` is in the (improbable) case where the url includes the username *and* password: `http://username:password@domain.com/...`

Comment: Git supports many different URL formats, at least a few of which aren't going to work with your cut commands. See the git push man page [section on URL formats](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#URLS). In my case, I get 'git' as the user, because the url is formatted as `ssh://git@host/~user/repo.git`, but, I'll admit this looks like a strange edge case, and your solution should work for most cases.

Comment: @ZoeyHewll Yes, this is mainly for HTTPS URL. If you get 'git', you know the username is not used in the URL.